# Scale-up Kafka without downtime

Tags: apache-kafka

Lets say that we have a service A,B and a Kafka Broker in different VMs.
Service_A is the producer, Service_B is the consumer.

If Kafka can't handle workload then:

a) How can it scale-up without downtime?

Also,

b) Can number of partitions change in real-time without downtime?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to both is yes, but scaling **out** Kafka (adding brokers) will not add partitions to existing topics; you'll need to manually invoke `kafka-reassign-partitions` command, which requires brokers to be running.

The main problem you may run into with that is if there are clients actively using some partition on a broker and you completely move it off to a different broker.

You cannot reduce partitions, ever.

Comment: So if I reassign the partitions then the producers and consumers how will act? Should I write scripts for reassign and clients to partition leader or kafka can do it alone?

Comment: They may retry the request if the leader changes. It'll act similar if the leader broker died on its own. Producers can only write to the leader partition at any time. Consumers can consume from insync replicas, if configured to do so